# queryDSL MathExpressions power function

Tags: java, querydsl

Query `DSL` `MathExpressions` power function has the following syntax.

power:

```
public static <A extends Number & Comparable<?>> 
  NumberExpression<Double> power(Expression<A> num, int exponent).
```

We are trying to use it as

```
MathExpressions.power(Expressions.constant(new Integer(10)),
  xyz.amtScale.intValue());
```

In this scenario, we have the DB column, `amtScale(NumberPath)`, as an exponent value.

How can we convert a `NumberExpression` to primitive int value?

Comment: Do you mean how to use this expression in a query or something else? I am not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: we have the exponent value stored in DB. How to use the MathExpressions.power function in this case? We can get the handle to the column as Expression, but how to convert it to int.

Comment: Just use it in a projection query.from(...).where(...).uniqueResult(powerExpression);

Comment: Hi Timo, we used MathOps in the following way. SimpleExpression<Double> expScale = SimpleOperation.create(
                Double.class, Ops.MathOps.POWER,
                Expressions.constant(new Integer(10)), amountScale); This allows Expression for both "num" and "exponent".